# mkdir(): File existed (Yii2)

Tags: yii2

I am getting this error when trying to create new directory. What I don't understand is that when I use `$folderGallery = mkdir($dir.$modelGallery->gallery_id, 0777, true);`, it does not work, but when I change to `$modelGallery->gallery_name`, it is successfully created.

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;

$modelGallery= new Gallery();

//die(count($modelEulogy));

if ($modelGallery->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
{
    if($modelGallery->validate())
    {
        $dir = 'img/'.$session['UserID'].'/album/';

        //die($modelGallery->gallery_id);

        if(!file_exists($dir))
            $folderGallery = mkdir($dir.$modelGallery->gallery_id, 0777, true);
        else
            $folderGallery = mkdir($dir.$modelGallery->gallery_id, 0777, true);


        //$model->gallery_id = $id;
        $modelGallery->user_id = $session['UserID'];
        $modelGallery->date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $modelGallery->save();
    }
    return $this->redirect(['index', 'gallery_id'=>$id]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check the existing directory

```
$path = $dir.$modelGallery->gallery_id;
if (!is_dir($path)) {
    mkdir($dir.$modelGallery->gallery_id, 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: The result shows the file is exist but its not exist yet in the folder. gallery_id is auto increment integer. i want to create new folder with ID name.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`FileHelper::createDirectory()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basefilehelper#createDirectory()-detail) - it will do any necessary checks for you. You should also use absolute paths to avoid ambiguous path resolution:

```
$dir = '@webroot/img/'.$session['UserID'].'/album/';
FileHelper::createDirectory(Yii::getAlias($dir . $modelGallery->gallery_id, 0777, true));
```